# Rails/Backbone.js content with script tag shows error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, wysiwyg, hamlc

I have an app that has page content that includes script tags, but when it tries to render it gives the error 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL'.

I'm initializing a backbone app as follows:

```
- content_for :javascript do
  - javascript_tag do
    App.initialize({ data: #{@data.to_json.html_safe } });
```

which generates the following JSON:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
App.initialize({ data: {"content":"<div style=\"padding-left:5px;\"><script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"http://www.opentable.com/frontdoor/default.aspx?rid=52900&restref=52900&bgcolor=8AA86B&titlecolor=0F0F0F&subtitlecolor=0F0F0F&btnbgimage=http://www.opentable.com/frontdoor/img/ot_btn_black.png&otlink=FFFFFF&icon=light&mode=short&hover=1\"></script></div>"});
//]]>
</script>
```

I'm trying to render it as follows (with hamlc):

```
- if @page.attributes.content
  .text.page-content~ @page.attributes.content
```

Comment: It points to the line in the html that has the initialize function with all of the JSON.  If I take the script tag out, it renders fine, while if I leave it in it throws that error.  So it's essentially pointing at the content with the script tag.

Comment: Added that chunk of JSON above.

Comment: So you have `</script>` inside a JavaScript string inside a `<script>` element?

Comment: Well played, I think that's true.  Do I need to escape the '/'s or something?

Comment: Actually, it's in quotes, why does that matter?

Comment: The `</script>` inside the string is probably being interpreted as the closing match for your `<script type="text/javascript">`. You need to mangle the string into `...</sc' + 'ript>...` or similar; or you could move that into a separate `.js` file so that you don't have to worry about it. Do some searching and you should find the standard solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of Chad from [Thoughtbot.com](https://learn.thoughtbot.com/prime), I was pointed to the following blog post.  Apparently this is a "flaw" with json escaping. http://jfire.io/blog/2012/04/30/how-to-securely-bootstrap-json-in-a-rails-view/

First override the json function.

`config/initializers/json_escape.rb`

```
class ActionView::Base
  def json_escape(s)
    result = s.to_s.gsub('/', '\/')
    s.html_safe? ? result.html_safe : result
  end

  alias j json_escape
end
```

(restart your server)

And in your rails view use the `j` function before your ruby code:

```
- content_for :javascript do
  - javascript_tag do
    App.initialize({ data: #{j @data.to_json.html_safe } });
```

Answer (score 0):

With the given JSON Snippet, the server side will generate the the following JavaScript tah content to bootstrap the app:

```
App.initialize({ data: "content":"<div>...</div>" });
```

Which is not valid JavaScript. You need to wrap the `data` key intro an object itself, like:

```
App.initialize({ data: { "content":"<div>...</div>" }});
```

so you should end up with the following server side Haml:

```
- content_for :javascript do
  - javascript_tag do
    App.initialize({ data: { #{@data.to_json.html_safe } } });
```

Comment: I'm sorry, my source does have the curly brackets around it.  I'll update my question.